# Is dimensional analysis valid for integrals

Tags: integration, dimensional-analysis

Can we apply dimensional analysis for variables inside integrals? Ex: if we have integral $$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} = \frac{1}{a} \sin^{-1} \left(\frac{a}{x}\right),$$ the LHS has no dimensions, while the RHS has dimensions of $\frac{1}{length}$. So let me know , whether I am correct?

Comment: The answers in this Math.SE question are related: [What does a triple integral represent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747317/what-does-a-triple-integral-represent/1747352#1747352)

Comment: You have made a mistake in the integration. :(

Answer (score 41):

Yes, you can apply dimensional analysis to integrals. You count differentials like $dx$ as having the units of the associated variable, because $dx$ can be interpreted as an infinitesimal change in $x$.

In your example, if $a$ and $x$ have units of distance, then checking the units in your result shows that it's incorrect. The correct integral does not have the  factor of $1/a$.

Comment: If the function is dimensionless then the integral $\int^a_b f(x)dx$ has units of area or it is dimensionless?

Comment: Antonios Sarikas: I think your integral should have units of length.

Answer (score 17):

To be more explicit about Ben Crowell's remarks:
Let $u = \frac xa$, so $dx = adu$ and the integration becomes $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} = \int \frac{adu}{\sqrt{a^2-a^2u^2}} = \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} = \sin^{-1} u + C = \sin^{-1}\frac xa + C$$
(assuming that $a> 0$).

Since $a$ and $x$ must have the same units for the expression $a^2 - x^2$ to make sense, we see that $u$ is dimensionless, as is the integrand in all 3 versions, and as is the correct integral.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you may. Think of an integral $\int g(x) dx$ as the sum $\sum g(x) \Delta x$. In each term in your (very large) summation, you may apply dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Your integral has a symmetry:  if you map $a \mapsto k a$ and then $x \mapsto kx$ your RHS reads:

$$ \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{x} \mapsto \sin^{-1} \frac{ka}{kx} = \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{x} $$

That went well... what about the left hand side?  Does was that also invariant?

$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}} \mapsto \int \frac{d(kx)}{\sqrt{(ka)^2 -(kx)^2}} = \int \frac{k\,dx}{k\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}} = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}}$$
So - by the rules of calculus - these integrals are both fixed points of the rescaling action $(a,x) \mapsto (ka,kx)$.  We really needed the linearity of the integral and differential here $\int$ and $d$.

There may even be other symmetries.  For one thing, RHS is *not* unless - it can be thought of as an angle $\theta$ with units of [*radians*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).  What happens when we change the integration constant $\theta \mapsto \theta + c $ ?

Comment: Angles are not unitless, but they are dimensionless in the usual dimension systems. In some calculation, you can distinguish “*parallel length*” and “*perpendicular length*” to get angles with dimension of $\frac{perpendicular\ length}{parallel\ length}$, but you can't do that generally.